# Problemas con Graphics y draw()

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial para aprender a crear un juego desde 0 en Java, estoy siguiendo cada línea de código al pie de la letra, pero aún así no consigo hacer que me muestre algo en pantalla, y no entiendo el porqué.

[El tutorial que estoy siguiendo es éste](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1nb0bdV-tE&list=PLHwsL1JI79K1CIS9P3Ik9ilOzMyYKElfG)

Ya voy por el video 3, pero no he conseguido que me muestre los FPS en pantalla. (De hecho, anteriormente la idea era mostrar un rectángulo con drawRect(), pero tampoco me mostró nada).
Les muestro mi código y una captura del JFrame en ejecución.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable{
public static final int WIDHT = 800, HEIGHT = 600;
private Canvas canvas;
private Thread thread;
private boolean running = false;
private BufferStrategy bs;
private Graphics g;
private final int FPS = 60;
private double TARGETTIME = 1000000000/FPS;
private double delta = 0;
private int AVERAGEFPS = FPS;

public Window() {
    initComponents();
    setTitle("Clash of Asteroids 1J");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDHT, HEIGHT));
    canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDHT, HEIGHT));
    canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDHT, HEIGHT));
    canvas.setFocusable(true);
    add(canvas);
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 600));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        


public static void main(String args[]) {

    new Window().start();
}

int x=0;
private void update(){
    x++;
}

private void draw(){
    bs = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        canvas.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    //-------------------------------------------
        g.drawString(""+AVERAGEFPS, 100, 100);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
    //-------------------------------------------
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    long now = 0;
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    int frames = 0;
    long time = 0;
    while(running){
        now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime)/TARGETTIME;
        time += (now - lastTime);
        lastTime = now;
        if(delta>=1){
            update();
            draw();
            delta--;
            frames++;
        }
        if(time >= 1000000000){
            AVERAGEFPS = frames;
            frames = 0;
            time = 0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}

private void start(){
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    running = true;
}

private void stop(){
    try {
        thread.join();
        running = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration 
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, no me está mostrando la cifra de frames. Un amigo mío lo intentó hacer en Eclipse pero tampoco le funcionó, y eso que él descargó el código fuente del repositorio original.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el metodo `draw` no entiendo la razón de ser del `return`, de todos modos el problema es que `bs` tiene que estar dentro del condicional `if(bs==null)` solo basta con obtener una sola vez el `bufferStrategy`, se puede sin usar `canvas`, por otro lado se necesita también que la vista se refresque, sino se verá cada repintado encima de otro, entonces serian totalmente ilegibles los numeros de `AVERAGEFPS`, eso se logra con `clearRect()`.

Quedaría así después de un pequeño cambio estético con un `drawRect`, colores y tal...

```
private void draw(){
    /*bs = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        canvas.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }*/
    if(bs==null) {
      createBufferStrategy(3);
      bs=getBufferStrategy();
    }
    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    //-------------------------------------------
        g.clearRect(0,0,getSize().width,getSize().height);
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(90,80,40,30);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString(""+AVERAGEFPS, 100, 100);
    //-------------------------------------------
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

Comment: ¡De la que me salvaste!